# JSON Parse works on localhost but not Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, heroku

The JSON Parse Controller works on my local computer but not when I upload it to Heroku.  There are no errors in the Heroku error log when trying to run it, but I do get the error below when I try "bundle exec heroku restart"

```
acpk-air% bundle exec heroku restart    
Could not find json-1.8.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Running Bundle Install doesn't help.

Code that works on localhost but not production:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'net/http'

class MeetupController < ApplicationController

    respond_to :json
    $meetupRI = ENV["MEETUP_API_URL"]

    def getEvents
        response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse($meetupRI))
        data = response.body
        parsed_response = JSON.parse(data)
        parsed_response["results"].each do |event|
            if Event.where(:foreign_id => event["id"]).blank?
                if event["venue"].blank?
                    e = Event.new(:name => event["name"], :description => event["description"], :url => event["event_url"], :start_time => DateTime.strptime(event['time'].to_s,'%Q'), :foreign_id => event["id"])
                else
                    e = Event.new(:name => event["name"], :description => event["description"], :url => event["event_url"], :start_time => DateTime.strptime(event['time'].to_s,'%Q'), :foreign_id => event["id"], :location => event["venue"]["name"])
                end
                e.save
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Try following this link https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2780. This might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess I was tired yesterday.  I forgot to include: ruby '2.1.3' in the Gemfile.